# Voip conference implementation

Tags: audio, voip, rtp, conference

Hi I need some information on how to implement Voip (RTP) audio conference. I need an algorithm description. Can someone point me to relevant resource on web.

Answer (score 1):

[FreeSWITCH](http://www.freeswitch.org/) is a open source, which has a support for Audio conferencing upto 10,000 simultaneous calls (may be more). You *may* not find any conferencing algorithm lying open. Search for white papers on audio mixing.

Answer (score 1):

The RFCs are the obvious starting points.

- https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3550
- https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3551

I'm not sure what algorithms you are asking for, but the RFCs contains algorithms for RTCP and other things.